# Batch convert to UTF-8 a directory having both UTF-8 and CP-1251 files

Tags: linux, batch, conversion, encoding, utf-8

I have a directory containing files, some of them are UTF-8, some are CP-1251. I want to convert the ones that are CP-1251 to be UTF-8, but without corrupting the UTF-8 files.

I tried using `iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 <...>`, it works for CP-1251, but if the file is already UTF-8, it is also converted and becomes incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it using [enconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enconv):

```
enconv -L bulgarian -x utf8 file.txt
```

It works for both UTF-8 and CP-1251 files.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a list of files that are neither UTF-8 nor US-ASCII using:

```
file -0 -i *.txt | awk -F '\0' '$2 !~ /charset=(us-ascii|utf-8)$/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: Just a minor correction - I tried it, but it showed the files that are UTF-8, instead of those that "are neither UTF-8 nor US-ASCII".